# Table rendering in editor, but not in question

Tags: bug, editor, tables

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67062117/is-there-a-google-sheets-formula-to-produce-a-conditional-sum-spanning-multipl#67062117). Their Markdown table does not render as a table on the question. I went to edit it, but in the editor, it renders fine! (While writing this post, the author commented, reporting similar behavior on their end.)

Live question:

[image]

Question In Editor:

[image]